# Put application created by eclipse on appstore (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

Will I face any problems if i want to add an application created by Eclipse onto the Android Play Store? Many people told me that the store will not support Eclipse. I'm almost done with my application, and if Eclipse is indeed no longer supported, would it be easy to open my application with Android Studio?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a **programming** issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You won't find any problem if you upload the application created by Eclipse, but it is recommended that you better switch to Android studio but if you plan to stick to Eclipse you should check this out - https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.andmore/

Google stopped support for Eclipse means Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android development.

Comment: Android studio so slow compare to Eclipse so i use eclipse :)